Slowly Changing Dimensions - capture for ETL to a Dimensionalised Data Warehouse
Starting point: On premises relational Data Warehouse
Target: GCP Dimensionally modelled Big Query
Does anyone know of a Tool which can distinguish/recognise a pattern of attributes making up a Slowly Changing Dimension and then ETL that into Big Query ?
Sort of Business Event Pattern matching on SCD's - kinda Spanner on Steroids ?
Was looking at Qlerify to quantify Events and build a Star Schema visualisation.  Spit out the DDL into Big Query and "Somehow" do a Pattern Search in the Source for candidates to use in the ETL...
Tall order I know but fortune favours the brave.  Someones gonna tell me I'm innately stupid.  Am good with that too but at least I'll know I "Aimed too high" :-)

Hi - can you explain, possibly with examples, what you mean by “ distinguish/recognise a pattern of attributes making up a Slowly Changing Dimension”?

Hi, Sure - so the dimension is derived from a Historic Value (type2).  Or a RollUp from a more granular dimension eg Month a roll up of Calendar containing Month, quarter, year and so on

So is there any way I can work out what the hierarchy of a dimension is?  Is it single or multi parent, is it balanced, ragged or variable depth?  Maybe a lineage tool can give me this characterisation ?

Only if you've constructed your dimensions in a way that allows you to characterise them in this way. As there is no standard for these characterisations, no tool is going to understand them out of the box - unless, possibly, your ETL tool does.

Hi Nick, as I wrote it I came rhetorically to the same conclusion.  I REALLY appreciate the Sanity Check.  THANKS
